# How to work with variable with React Component in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to have a state variable with React component in it as so:

```
this.state = {
    tile: <Tile />
}
```

I can easily render this component in my render method by `{this.state.tile}`, however what if I want to call a method inside of `<Tile/>` component? Let's assume a button with onClick function, as so:

```
<button onClick={() => {this.state.tile.changeType("test")}}>Click</button>
```

and

```
export default class Tile extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
    }

    changeType(type)
    {
        var tState = this.state
        tState.type = type
        this.setState(tState)
    }
}
```

The method `changeType` is not being called and React gives me error. I have stumbled upon React refs, but I have trouble setting them up to this specific way.

Comment: If you need to call a method on a child component, that's likely a code smell, and you should be passing the function to the child component instead, using either the parent component's state or context or hooks.

Comment: @ZacAnger Context is understandable, but what if I want to have an array of `Tile`?

Comment: Then you could map over the data producing the array, for example `{someData.map((data, index) => <Tile data={data} key={index} />}` (along with any other props, including the passed-down functions if needed).